# Does delayed graduation affect graduate school acceptance largely?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm double majoring philosophy and Japanese in Asia, I transfered from the philosophy department and applied for philosophy as a double major, additionally, I'm trying to complete a program ran by the school related to translation and interpretation.
The issue is, I need more time.
I'm already a senior, but it will take me 5 more semesters(the following spring semester included) to finish all of the workloads.
It makes me nervous, thinking about whether should I compelete "ALL" of my studies, or just pick one(likely philosophy) and graduate as soon as possible.

Going to grad school(for T&I) would mean a lot to my future plans, but I still want to finish my studies, I don't really know if these two ideas are conflicted.

Does graduate school take in consideration how much time I spent on the bachelors degree?
If they do, does having two degrees and a program certification sound persuasive enough for the extra time spent?

Thank you in advance for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read it correctly, you are (a) getting a double major and (b) getting separate degree in a different field. If that is correct then I think that you should be fine.

Five additional semesters would otherwise raise some questions.

In general, though delayed graduation being a problem would depend on why, exactly, the delay. In this case it might even be a positive. If it were caused by a poor academic record it would probably be otherwise.

Another issue, however, that might arise is your commitment to a field of study. Graduate study usually requires specialization. You can probably address that in any application, and there are also exceptions to that "rule".

---

Note, however, that this is also a US-centric answer.